# set CapsLock as Esc, and Ctrl when pressed in combination

Tags: keyboard, vim, xmodmap

I would like to set <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd> when pressed alone, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when pressed in combination with another key.

This is possible in karabiner-Elements for MacOS, but i cant find an easy way to do it on Ubuntu. Xmodmap perhaps?

I was having trouble with it, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds impossible. As soon as you press Caps once it would be interpreted as an Escape. If you were to hold Caps down it would be repeated as many Escape's. So I think you can remap CAPS to ESC or you can remap CAPS to CTRL but not both.

Comment: it is not impossible. as i state, its possible on macOS

Answer (score 3):

You could try the combination of setxkbmap and xcape. After installing the packages, type the following in a terminal:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape' -t 175
```

Caps lock will now act as Escape when pressed and Ctrl when held.

Comment: what's the `-t 175` for? It works perfectly fine without.

Comment: @a-sf-d how can I do single press caps lock and long press with another key as ctrl?

Comment: @Wolfson _"-t Give a timeout in milliseconds.  If you hold a key longer than timeout a key event will not be generated."._

It makes it nicer in cases where you intend to press ctrl-<something> but you just press ctrl, hesitate a bit then release. In those situations you don't really want ESC to be fired.

Comment: interesting! my ubuntu machine died so it may be awhile before ill need to try this out, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds impossible. As soon as you press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> once it would be interpreted as an <kbd>Escape</kbd>. If you were to hold <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> down it would be repeated as many Escape's. So I think you can remap <kbd>CAPS</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd> or you can remap <kbd>CAPS</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> but not both.

The reason you can press and hold <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> without repeats is because they are known as ***Modifier*** keys and do not send a keystroke until another non-modifier key is pressed.

Comment: it is not impossible. as i stated, it can be done on macOS

Comment: I hope it is possible, but it "sounds" impossible. Is the Mac OS using and IBM 105 key compatible keyboard? Hopefully someone from the Apple world can serve up an IBM/Microsoft keyboard scan code answer for you.